# poedit shows errors that cant seem to be fixed

Tags: translation, poedit

im having a problem with PoEdit I used a software called PO-Auto-Translator to translate a po file and once it was done i wanted to continue editing the file with poedit, when i try to save i get many errors...

```
    04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:46: missing 'msgstr' section
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:46:22: syntax error
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:51: missing 'msgstr' section
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:51:22: syntax error
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:52: keyword "$s" unknown
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:795: keyword "Upload" unknown
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:795:55: syntax error
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:1583: missing 'msgstr' section
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:1583:27: syntax error
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:1584: keyword "s" unknown
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:1597:28: syntax error
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:1597: keyword "s" unknown
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:4162:14: syntax error
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:4163: end-of-line within string
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:4167:14: syntax error
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:4167: keyword "Admin" unknown
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:4168: end-of-line within string
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:4172:14: syntax error
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:4173: end-of-line within string
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Users\home\Desktop\translation.po:4176:31: syntax error
04/21/14 22:39:12: C:\Program Files (x86)\Poedit\GettextTools\bin\msgfmt.exe: too many errors, aborting
```

i compared the file to other files who dont show this error and didnt find a problem with it.

here are the first 50 lines of the translation

```
# Translation of translation
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: translation\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2012-12-05 10:43+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2014-04-21 22:39+0200\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: AppThemes\n"
"Language: en\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.6.4\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: __;_e;_n:1,2;_nx:1,2;_x:1,2c;_ex:1,2c;esc_attr__;esc_attr_e;esc_attr_x:1,2c;esc_html__;esc_html_e;esc_html_x:1,2c;_n_noop:1,2;_nx_noop:1,2,3c\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: .\n"

#: 404.php:22
msgid "Whoops! Page Not Found."
msgstr "אופס! דף לא נמצא."

#: 404.php:24
#: 404.php:44 search.php:77 includes/theme-actions.php:218
msgid "Sponsored Links"
msgstr "קישורים ממומנים"

#: attachment.php:19
#, php-format
msgid "Return to %s"
msgstr "חזור אל% s"

#: attachment.php:20
#, php-format
msgid "&larr; Return to %s"
msgstr "? חזור אל% s"

#: attachment.php:31
#, php-format
msgid "<span class="%1$s">By</span> %2$s"  /line 46
msgstr "ש"

#: attachment.php:44
#, php-format
msgid "<span class="%1$s">Uploaded</span> %2$s"
msgstr "<span class="%1$s">Uploaded</span> %2$s"

#: attachment.php:55
#, php-format
msgid "Full size is %s pixels"
msgstr "גודל מלא הוא פיקסלים% s"
```

can anyone see whats the problem of my file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your PO file is invalid — it doesn't follow PO file format syntax and doesn't escape quotes within string literals. `msgid "foo"bar"` is invalid, unlike `msgid "foo\"bar"`, similarly to C, PHP or many other languages.

IMNSHO, you should ditch whatever tool produced such horribly broken PO files (it definitely wasn't Poedit as the `X-Generator` header would imply) immediately and replace it with something that actually knows its output format. Such as `xgettext`, *the* standard tool for gettext strings extraction. It supports PHP just fine.

If the tool is something homegrown, here's a *very* good description of the PO format by Chusslove Illich of Pology: http://pology.nedohodnik.net/doc/user/en_US/ch-poformat.html (unofficial, but much better than GNU gettext's own manual). If you write or read PO files in any of your code, I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reading this and having trouble debugging errors showing in POEdit from your po files, you can run:

```
msgfmt -v -c mypofile.po
```

It will show every error shown in your po file with the line associated to it.

Also, you can use `Catalogue > Purge Deleted Translations` from the POEdit menu that will save you a ton of issues and making your po file lighter.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I need to manually add `\` next to every `"` where poedit gave the error... Little by little I fixed it and it works :)